# Unexpected horizontal scrollbar coming on mobile screen size?

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, scrollbar

I have created one wordpress website and in that if you view this site in mobile size there will be horizontal scrollbar , how can we remove it ?

this is my website link http://demo.proserindustries.com/

Comment: It's possible that one of your assets have excessive width than the rest of the website. See if any image doesn't have an 'img-fluid' class or it's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'overflow: hidden`to your`bgimg`class. Actually, you see a horizontal scroll when the size of the heading`h1` exceeds the width of the page on some mobiles

or

you can apply css `word-break: break-word` on your heading tag... this is not very elegant solution, but would work in some cases also

Comment: Let me check this all possibilities